# Как разделить строку на список слов разделённых пробелами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Например у меня есть :

```
"I like apple."
```

Как сделать так чтобы было :

```
["I", "like", "apple"]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
s = "I like apple."
lst = s.split()

print(lst) # ['I', 'like', 'apple.']
```

Если нужно без точки, то

```
s = "I like apple."
lst = s.replace('.', '').split()

print(lst) # ['I', 'like', 'apple']
```

Метод `split()` (без параметров) у строки разделяет строку на список, для разделения `separator` по умолчанию None

> что означает любое количество пробельных символов

Про None поправил [@pank](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198501/pank)

Comment: `sep` по умолчанию `= None`, что означает любое количество пробельных символов: `" aaa \t\n bbb    ccc\n\n".split() ==['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']`.

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы строку разбить по пробелам на переменные?

Comment: @DirBeer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop